# How to create FacebookSession manually when authenticating with FB.login JavaScript SDK

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I am currently using Facebook C# SDK most recent version with Facebook's JavaScript SDK framework.  I am doing a combination of AJAX for a registration form.  I can see that in the FacebookWebContext.Current there is a method for deleting the FacebookAuthCookie.  The problem is when I login with FB.login function.  I am not sure how to create a FacebookSession so that it works the way it should so that I can use FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated to deteremine if they are logged in on the server side.

How can I go about this?  I have looked all over the place and find no good examples of how to create the Facebook Session Cookie...

Any pointers?  Thanks!

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you login using FB.login() and it is successful, it automatically generates your session. You can get it in the callback you specified in the FB.login, [see here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/). It is the **response.session** object.

Comment: Are you saying when I am successfully logged in, it will already make the cookie for me?  So when and if I refresh the page or send an Ajax Request it should return true when doing FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated() ??  if that is the case thats good to know and your answer helps... If not then I guess I am not understanding then.

Comment: Yes, that is true, as long as the browser accepts cookies and the like, which is enabled by default.